# How to setup ember-simple-auth if rails is handling the login forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Im a bit stuck. I dont know how to setup ember-simple-auth with my current rails + ember-cli app.

Currently, the user has to login with steam, so they get redirected to steam's login page. When they press authorize, they get redirected back to my site. I then let rails process the request and if they successfully signed in with steam, I set a cookie with a randomly generated token.

Now I need to do two things for ember-simple-auth.

1. Tell ember-simple-auth to check if the token exists, and if it does, make an api call to get the user's infor like the name, email, username, etc...
2. Add a prefilter that passes the token in most requests.

For #2, I can just use the OAuth authorizer, but for #1, I have no idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a custom authenticator and use that to authenticate the session in an initializer when the app starts. The authenticator would in its `authenticate` method read the token that the Rails app writes to the cookie, make the API call and resolve with a bearer token that the OAuth 2.0 authorizer would then inject into requests.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect! :)

Comment: How can I store something like username, first_name, last_name, etc? Where do I put the code for that?

Comment: I just used the generator to create the authenticator, and this is what I got: https://gist.github.com/nahtnam/82e1e8d97272f80ca862 I tried looking at one of your implementations: https://goo.gl/HK8iGE but I dont understand how it all works.

Comment: NVM, someone else helped me.